# ArrayPlot : Strange behaviour

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to "ArrayPlot" data generated from another code.
I need to do it for different dimensions.
Below a certain size everything works properly but from some value for the dimension it doesn't work anymore.
The .txt files I import  are constructed as follow.

1.234,2.567,8.987

4.567,9.543,6.567

4.890,78.56,76.87

as you can see it represents a n by n matrix.
The code I use is the following

```
Husimi = Import["/Users/.../dataexample.txt", {"Data"}];


ArrayPlot[Husimi]
```

Everything is working fine for matrix up to the dimension n=288,
The following case is n=544 and then it doesn't work anymore.
The output is a thin vertical line. It seems to me that mathematica is treating my data as a unidimensional list taking every line of my file as a unique element.
Any idea why ? I have the feeling that this case is very dumb but I am stuck.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Try using `AspectRatio` option, for example: `ArrayPlot[Husimi, AspectRatio -> 1]`. If that doesn't solve your problem, there might be something wrong with your data (so please also post the screenshot).

Comment: Please post the link about the `n=544` data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete the empty lines, they will result in empty rows.

Then either store the file with an extension "csv"  (comma separated values). Then everything will work:

```
d = Import["d:/tmp/dat.csv"]
ArrayPlot[d]

{{1.234, 2.567, 8.987}, {4.567, 9.543, 6.567}, {4.89, 78.56, 76.87}}
```

[image]

However, if you insists of using a file extension of "txt", you must specify the format explicitly:

```
d = Import["d:/tmp/dat.txt", "CSV"]
```

Comment: Many thank,
Changing Data to CSV in code works fine.